# How do I show that this Limit of 2 variables is zero?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I show that :$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0?$$
I'm stumped...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
0 \le (x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2 - 2xy\implies|xy| \le \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}
$$

Answer (score 7):

$$0\leq|xy|\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{x^2+y^2}\leq |xy|\to0$$

Comment: Spot on, short, and sweet!

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of some variety in answers, let's see how this goes with the polar substitution $x  = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y  = r\sin(\theta)$ note:
$$ xy \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} =  r^4 \frac{ \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))}{r^2} = r^2 h(\theta)$$
Clearly $h(\theta)$ is bounded as $r \rightarrow 0$ hence
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} xy \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r^2h(\theta) = 0. $$
Of course, the method suggested by the other answers is more rigorous, but in the event the limit does not exist this method sometimes reveals how to obtain inconsistent path limits.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would take a change of coordinates and look at the limit in polar coordinates.

Substituting $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, we get

\begin{array}
xxy \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} &=& r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin^2\theta} \\ \\
&\equiv& r^2(\cos^3\theta\sin\theta - \cos\theta\sin^3\theta) \\ \\
&\equiv& \frac{r^2}{4}\sin 4\theta
\end{array}

As $r \to 0$, this tends towards 0 for all values of $\theta$.

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r^2$ you have sine missing in the denominator.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thanks for spotting the typo'.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$ if,  and only if, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|f(x,y)|=0$. Note that, $|x^2-y^2 |\leq | x^2+y^2|$ implies
$$
0
\leq
\left| xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \right|
\leq 
|x||y|\cdot\left| \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|
\leq
|x||y|
$$
By the sandwich theorem the inequalities
$$
0
\leq 
\left| xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \right|
\leq
|xy|
$$
and $
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}0 =0 $,$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|xy|=0
$
implies 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left| xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \right|=0
$$